# Why my nginx redirection doesnt work

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, 301-redirect

I`m trying to do redirection via Nginx
webmail.mywebsite.to to gmail.com

I`m trying with

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name webmail.mywebsite.com;
  return      301 https://www.gmail.com;
}
```

But I stil get error

> webmail.mywebsite.com server IP address could not be found.

I'm usin ec2 (where I install SSL ) and I'm using Route53 for my domain too ..

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the DNS entry for `webmail.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thank you so much for quick answer. Yo think I should put RECORD on Route53 with my SERVER IP on webmail.mywebsite.com and then try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the notification you attached, webmail.mywebsite.com not resolv in your network.

Im suggest you to add A record for webmail.mywebsite.com on your DNS Zone.

If you already add A record for webmail.mywebsite.com then you must be waiting for DNS Propagation to resolving your DNS Record to all network.

You can do a make sure by mapping the hostname locally at `/etc/hosts` (linux) or `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` (windows).